# dynamically change the where conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic, plsql, build-automation

I want to retrieve records from one table based on where conditions stored in another table. Currently I'm storing column names and constraints applied to them in that table. I fetch them one by one using cursor and apply to my query.

```
DECLARE 
cursor c_checks
is
select FIELD_NAME,CHECKS from table_checks

BEGIN
for i in c_checks loop
INSERT INTO Results_Table
(SELECT c.*,'wrong product' Error_field FROM My_table c
WHERE i.FIELD_NAME||' '||i.CHECKS); 
Exit when c_checks%notfound;
End loop;
END;
```

And table_checks is as follows:

```
FIELD_NAME   CHECKS

Attribute1    IS NULL
Attribute2    IS NULL
Attribute3    > Attribute2
Attribute4    IS DATE
```

But it is not working as expected. Is there any way to modify this or any other way that I can achieve this. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @RomanKonoval's answer, I'll modify your code to build the statement dynamically and execute it:

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR c_checks IS SELECT FIELD_NAME, CHECKS FROM TABLE_CHECKS;
  strInsert  VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN c_checks LOOP
    strInsert := 'INSERT INTO RESULTS_TABLE ' ||
                   ' (SELECT c.*, 'wrong product' Error_field ' ||
                       'FROM MY_TABLE c ' ||
                       'WHERE ' || i.FIELD_NAME || ' ' || i.CHECKS || ')'; 

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('strInsert=' || strInsert);

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strInsert;
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLCODE || ' : ' || SQLERRM);
    RAISE;
END;
```

Here the `INSERT` statement is assembled in a string variable, and is then executed using the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement. Give this a try.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: wowww, I also wrote almost similar code just sometime ago. Done with it already. Big thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011). It allows you to construct query at run-time.

> Dynamic SQL is a programming methodology for generating and running
>   SQL statements at run time. It is useful when writing general-purpose
>   and flexible programs like ad hoc query systems, when writing programs
>   that must run database definition language (DDL) statements, or when
>   you do not know at compilation time the full text of a SQL statement
>   or the number or data types of its input and output variables.

Comment: I've tried the other way by inserting statement into a string from the checks table and execute it as **exec(string_query)**   still, nothing

Comment: Then you need to update your question and describe what you've tried and what is not working. 'Nothing' - is too vague

Comment: actualy, I'm using **Toad for oracle** and it doesn't recognize "@" in statement "@squery varchar(200)" . So, it isn't letting me start.